# Getting error for 2D array : subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, spiral

Hi I was writing the program for printing a 2D array in spiral order. But I am getting the below error `subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector`.

This is my code.

```
int *spiralOrder(const int** A, int n11, int n12, int *length_of_array) {
    *length_of_array = n11 * n12; // length of result array
    int *result = (int *)malloc(*length_of_array * sizeof(int));
    int top = 0, bottom = n11 - 1, left = 0, right = n12 - 1;
    int d = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (top <= bottom - 1 && left <= right - 1) {
        int i;
        if (d == 0) { //left to right
            for (i = 0; i < right; i++) {
                result[j++][k++] = A[top][i];
            }
            top++;
            d = 1;
        } else
        if (d == 1) { //top to bottom
            for (i = 0; i < bottom; i++) {
                result[j++][k++] = A[i][right];
            }
            right--;
            d = 2;
        } else
        if (d == 2) { //bottom right to left
            for (i = right; i >= left; i--) {
                result[j++][k++] = A[bottom][i];
            }
            bottom--;
            d = 3;
        } else
        if (d == 3) {  //bottom left to top
            for (i = bottom; i >= top; i--) {
                result[j++][k++] = A[i][left];
            }
            left++;
            d = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I want to save the result in `result` array. I saw answers for these error but most of them are dealing with 1D array. Can someone help.

Comment: `result` is a pointer. You can index it like a 1D array. But you are indexing it like a 2D array?

Comment: could you help me to do like that ?

Answer (score 1):

You `malloc`ed `result` as a 1-dimensionnal array, and you're using it as a bidemsnionnal array.

Assuming you have two variables `row_number` and `col_number` for the array size, you should allocate `result` like this (and don't forget to `free()`):

```
int **result;
result = (int**) malloc(row_number * sizeof(int*));
for(int i=0; i<row_number; i++)
{
    result[i] = (int*) malloc(col_number * sizeof(int));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are creating result as int* but using it as int**.
Second, use int** const instead of const int** if you were intended to not change the 2D array.
Last, you didn't implement logic correctly,
WAIT Read further only if you couldn't implement logic. Here is correct implementation: http://ideone.com/DfUD2T

```
int *spiralOrder(int** const A, int n11, int n12, int *length_of_array) {
    *length_of_array = n11 * n12; // length of result array
    int *result = (int *)malloc(*length_of_array * sizeof(int));
    int top = 0, bottom = n11 - 1, left = 0, right = n12 - 1;
    int j = 0, k = 0;
    while (top <= bottom - 1 || left <= right - 1) {
        int i;
         //left to right
            for (i = left; i <= right; i++) {
                result[j++] = A[top][i];
            }
            top++;
            //top to bottom
            for (i = top; i <= bottom; i++) {
                result[j++] = A[i][right];
            }
            right--;
            //bottom right to left
            for (i = right; i >= left; i--) {
                result[j++] = A[bottom][i];
            }
            bottom--;
              //bottom left to top
            for (i = bottom; i >= top; i--) {
                result[j++] = A[i][left];
            }
            left++;
    }
    return result;
}
```